# Filter on map of map

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have below map of map and want to filter it based on a value. The result should be assigned back to same map. Please let know what is the best approach for this.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> employeeMap;

<
 dep1, <"empid11", employee11> <"empid12",employee12>
 dep2, <"empid21", employee21> <"empid22",employee22>
>

Filter: employee.getState="MI"
```

I tried like below but i was not able to access the employee object

```
currentMap = currentMap.entrySet().stream()
            **.filter(p->p.getValue().getState().equals("MI"))**                    
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(),p->p.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to modify the map in place (and that it allows so), you can use `forEach` to iterate over the entries of the map, and then use `removeIf` for each values of the inner maps to remove the employees that satisfy the predicate:

```
employeeMap.forEach((k, v) -> v.values().removeIf(e -> e.getState().equals("MI")));
```

Otherwise, what you can do is to use the `toMap` collector, where the function to map the values takes care of removing the concerned employees by iterating over the entry set of the inner maps:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> employeeMap =
    employeeMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                              e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream().filter(emp -> !emp.getValue().getState().equals("MI")).collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try this