# Build a list of maximum values from a set of lists nested inside nested maps with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to java 8 and i need to rewrite an old piece of code to implement a new alghoritm.
The task is to filter the object which has max speed for each list. 
Lists are nested inside maps : a root map of roads , which contains maps of road segments and each map of road segments contains a list of objects , each one decribing measured speed at a time interval . I need to find all the maximum speeds for each list .

I've found the following links which looks like my problem, but i cannot adapt them, and i'm not sure my attempts solve my problem correctly.

[How do you filter nested loops using Java 8 streams and filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063533/how-do-you-filter-nested-loops-using-java-8-streams-and-filters)

[Java 8 Filter Map<String,List<Employee>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629897/java-8-filter-mapstring-listemployee)

[Filter on map of map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490526/filter-on-map-of-map)

this is the code i've used as example to write mine

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> employeeMap =
                            employeeMap.entrySet()
                                       .stream()
                                       .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                      e -> e.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                                                      .filter(emp -> !emp.getValue().getState().equals("MI"))
                                                      .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));


for(Car car : cars) {
                        for (Engine engine : car.getEngines()) {
                            for (Part part : engine.getParts()) {
                                // ...
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    cars.stream()
                        .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines().stream())
                        .flatMap(engine -> engine.getParts().stream())
                        .forEach(part -> {  ... });
```

this is my resulting code

```java
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<PartialSpeed>>> speedsPerRoadPerSegment; 


ArrayList<PartialSpeed> maxSpeedPerSegment = new ArrayList<PartialSpeed>();
                    speedsPerRoadPerSegment.entrySet().stream()
                            .forEach(road-> road.getValue().entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .forEach(segment ->
                            {
                                Optional<PartialSpeed> result = segment.getValue().stream()
                                .max(Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs));
                                maxSpeedPerSegment.add(result.get());
                            }));
```

All my attempt to adhere to the example had problems about result types not being recognized.
This is the best (not working) i'm been able to achieve :

```java
speedsPerRoadPerSegment.entrySet().stream()
                            .flatMap(road-> road.getValue().entrySet()
                            .stream().flatMap(
                                    segment -> segment .getValue()
                                    .stream()
                                    .max(Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs))
                                    ));
```

As you can see i've just replaced the old for loops with foreaches. I'd like to understand how to obtain the list of maximum elements directly from the lambda expression.

Comment: `Map<Road, Map<Segment, List<PartialSpeed>>>` is type of _speedsPerRoadPerSegment_?

Comment: @Hadi j yes , road and segment are just integer ids. I've edited the code. If something isn't clear please ask, i've translated variables names to english to make it more understandable.

Comment: Try this one `speedsPerRoadPerSegment.entrySet()
                .forEach(road ->
                        road.getValue().entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(segment -> segment.getValue()
                                        .stream().max(Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs))).
                                map(Optional::get)
                                .forEach(maxSpeedPerSegment ::add));` I have not tested it.

Comment: Or this one `speedsPerRoadPerSegment.entrySet().stream()
                .flatMap(road -> road.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                        .map(segment -> segment.getValue().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs)))
                        .map(Optional::get)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: @Hadi J your second answer generate the same error i got in my attempts : Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)  and Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Tbit75FfsParDay> to Stream<? extends Object> . Anyway thanks for your hints

Comment: Although Holger's answer is great but try this one too `speedsPerRoadPerSegment.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(road -> road.getValue().entrySet().stream())
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .filter(list->!list.isEmpty())
                .map(segment -> segment.stream()
                        .max(Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs)))
                .map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Hadi J +1 to your last example. It is very useful : i realize my mistake was not getting value from Map.Entry. I'll stick with Holger solution because as he says , i have to pick the right collection view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, whether you use a loop or stream, when processing a `Map`, you should pick the right collection view, `keySet()`, `entrySet()`, or `values()`, depending on which elements you actually need. Since you are only interested in the values, don’t use `entrySet()`.

Then, apply the right terminal operation to the stream, to get the final result:

```
List<PartialSpeed> maxSpeedPerSegment =
    speedsPerRoadPerSegment.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .map(list -> Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This uses `Collections.max` instead of a nested Stream operation, which will throw an exception if the collection is empty (just like calling `get()` on an `Optional` unconditionally will do).

If empty lists may occur, you may filter them before-hand:

```
List<PartialSpeed> maxSpeedPerSegment =
    speedsPerRoadPerSegment.values().stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
        .filter(list -> ! list.isEmpty())
        .map(list -> Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparing(PartialSpeed::getnVelFfs)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```